# How to keep center a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have Used a bootstrap menu, But I like to keep the menu content "{li}" in center. because the menu content "{li}" is not fixed. It might increase or reduce. Even It can be only 2 {li} as well. When I am keeping 2 {li} it's coming to left site which is not looking good. Hence, How can I keep the menu content {li} in center and it should work in responsive as well. Please Help me.

Thanks.
ATIK

Comment: Please add a fiddle showing us what you mean, or at least some code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try flexbox

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
nav ul {
    display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li a {
      padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">NAV #1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">NAV #2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">NAV #3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">NAV #4</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">NAV #5</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @AtikRahman could you mark this as complete if it answers your question please. Click the tick by my answer.

Comment: Another problem with bootstrap responsive Media screen menu. It's not Working well and it's breaking down on to the other content. Please help me again..